# How to get hidden field value in JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form which sends me some datas in PHP. And i want to add the Latitude and Longitude in the PHP request. My teacher told me to put my script into a input hidden to get the value of "adress" and change it to Latitude and Longitude (with a script I already do) during the PHP request.
I have no clue on how to do this, so if somebody can help me or explain me how, it will help me a lot.
Thanks

```
<div id="content">
  <form id="theForm" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h1>Déposez votre image!</h1>
    <div>
    <!--subname-->
      <input type="text" name="subname" id="input-text" placeholder="Titre de la photo" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <!--adress-->
      <input type="text" name="adress" id="input-text" placeholder="Adresse" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <!--image-->
      <input type="file" name="image" required>
    </div>
    <div>
    <!--about-->
      <textarea name="about" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Description de l'image" required></textarea>
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Image">
    </form>
  </div>
<script>
            var getLocation = function (address) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': address
                }, function (results, status) {

                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        console.log(latitude, longitude);
                    }
                });
            }
      getLocation('');
</script>
```

Comment: So what specifically is your issue? Don’t know how to get/set the value of a form field? Well that sounds like it should be easy enough to research, no?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="" />`, then in javascript put your value inside the hidden inputs. They will be sent with the request. Don't think your teacher think of something more complicated than this

Comment: How to write in the value of my input like
    <input type="hidden" value="getLocation"<?php echo(adress) ?> " />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 `inputs` with `type=hidden` for lat and lon inside your `<form>` as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="lat" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="lon" value="" />
```

In JS assign value to these hidden lat lon inputs like below:

```
var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

document.getElementById('lat').value = latitude;
document.getElementById('lon').value = longitude;
```

Apart from this a correction in your HTML. There cannot be 2 elements with same `ID`. You have used `id="input-text"` for 2 input fields. `ID` attribute should be unique. You may change it to `id="subname"` and `id="address"` respectively.

Comment: happy programming :)